# How to merge pdf documents generated with fo.net (xsl-fo)

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I use `fo.net` with success to generate one-page invoice pdf documents from `xsl-fo` template and xml data.
Now I would like to generate the pdf documents in a loop and write them to a `Stream`, so that I have the documents merged into just one batch pdf. Whenever I reach a certain number of documents I will create a new batch file and go on.

My problem: I generate the pdf documents one by one and append them to the batch file without errors, but the final pdf file shows only the first document. The file size has increased accordingly to the appended data but those pages are not shown. If I save each individual document they are OK, one page each. But the same documents appended to the file stream are not visible when opening the resulting file.

I tried with `fo:simple-page-master` and `fo:page-sequence-master`with a `fo:repeatable-page-master-reference`, with no success. As far as I have googled, I guess `fo.net` is not intended to be used this way.

My question is this: Is there a way to append pdf content to an existing pdf file (or stream) with `fo.net`? Or it simply can not be done?

I would like to confirm it before moving on to implement another solution, such as using some free tool to merge existing pdf documents (my best candidate for now is [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/)).

Another posible solution could be to generate the transformed xsl-fo containing already several pages, but I don't like this approach by performance reasons. The intermediate files would be quite great. I would prefer to keep in memory only one page at a time.

Perhaps my full approach to this problem is wrong, I would appreciate some ideas.

My environment: `.NET 4.0`, `Visual Studio 2010`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating PDFs is likely the wrong way to do it unless you have  very smart application. Reasons: images and fonts can be repeated in each document, making the resulting files very huge. Even worse, I have seen applications where one font table breaks others and you only get the characters in your final document that are inside of the last document appended. There are better ways with some products that have no limitations you mention.

See http://www.renderx.com/solutions/large_report_formatting.html for how it can be done with one XSL FO processor. Not sure you can adopt the ideas to yours. RenderX can process XSL FO in "append" mode, taking in and streaming out results while keeping image and font information to build a proper output. Perhaps your choice has a similar mode.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Brown for the interesting link and info. I was looking for a free solution, but RenderX and VDPMill are an option to consider for scalability reasons, I will have a look.